# Problems connecting to multifactor connection in share point one drive

Tags: python, sharepoint

Hola tengo problemas con la conexión desde python a share point de one drive de una base de datos (xlsx) y resulta que quiero acceder a un archivo excel pero me da este error.
Hubo un error al recuperar el token de respuesta XML: AADSTS50076: Debido a un cambio de configuración realizado por su administrador, o porque se ha trasladado a una nueva ubicación, debe utilizar la autenticación multifactor para acceder

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import pandas as pd

# File URL in SharePoint and credentials
url = 'https://companymy.sharepoint.com/personal/yo_compnay/Documents/prueba/document.xlsx'
username = 'yo@mycompany.com'
password = 'xxxx'

# Create authentication context
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)

# Attempt to acquire token with user authentication (username and password)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    # If authentication succeeds, create client context.
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth).

    # Get the binary file
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

    # Store data in a BytesIO stream object
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0) # Set file object at startup

    # Read the Excel file and each sheet in a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=None).
else:
    print("Error: failed multifactor authentication.")
```